# Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of null

Tags: reactjs, import, null, firebase-authentication, export

Hi all I am currently stuck with the following:

Cannot read property 'isLoggedIn' of null

```
>  9 | const Header = () => {
  10 |   const {isLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
  11 |   return (
  12 |     <ul className="nav">
```

I am new in React and I was following a tutorial to implement a sign-in/sign-up form and sending data to firebase (which is also something completely new to me). I was able to fix a couple of previous issues on my own but I am now stuck at this one.

If I don't import the Header into the Routing the site works fine but as soon as I try to import it in any way to Routing.js it's failing.

**Header.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import routes from "./routes";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./test";


const Header = () => {
  const {isLoggedIn} = useContext(AuthContext);
  return (
    <ul className="nav">
    {routes.map((route, i) => (
      <li key={i}>
        <Link to={route.path}>{route.name}</Link>
      </li>
    ))}
    {isLoggedIn && <li><Link to="/reports">Profile</Link></li>}
  </ul>
  )
}

export default Header;
```

**Routing.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Head from "./Head";
import Join from "./Join";
import Login from "./Login";
import Test from "./test";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import Header from "./Header";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Head />
    <HomePage />
      </div>
  );
}

function Reviews() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
  <Head />

  </div>
);
}

function Logging() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Head />
    <Header />
    <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

function Signup() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <Head />
    <Header />
    <Test />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/review" exact component={Reviews} />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Logging} />
        <Route path="/signup" exact component={Signup} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}


export default App;

import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Switch, BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "./routes.js";
import Header from "./Header";
import "./styles.css";

import * as firebase from "firebase";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebase.config";
import protectedRoutes from './protectedRoutes'


import ProtectedRouteHoc from './ProtectedRouteHoc'

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


export const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

function Test() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  function readSession() {
    const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(
            `firebase:authUser:${firebaseConfig.apiKey}:[DEFAULT]`
        );
        if (user) setLoggedIn(true)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    readSession()
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn }}>
      Is logged in? {JSON.stringify(isLoggedIn)}
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Header isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}/>

          <Switch>
            {protectedRoutes.map(route => (
              <ProtectedRouteHoc
                key={route.path}
                isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
                path={route.path}
                component={route.main}
                exact={route.exact}
                public={route.public}
              />
            ))}
            {routes.map(route => (
              <Route
                key={route.path}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={route.main}
              />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

I would appreciate any tips or things I can read through to get a better understanding in this.

Comment: The error message suggests that `useContext` is returning null.

Comment: Please update question with `isLoggedIn` context provider code/component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're destructing the return value of  `useContext(AuthContext)`. You're expecting it to return an object with a key `isLoggedIn`, e.g. `{ isLoggedIn: false }`, but it's returning `null` instead. You probably haven't given it a default value when you instantiated the context instance, e.g.

```
// Possibly what you're doing, no default value
const AuthContext = React.createContext() // null

// Instantiated with a default value
const AuthContext = React.createContext({ isLoggedIn: false })
```